# Permission problem accessing CodeCommit repository during build phase

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-amplify, aws-codecommit

I am struggling trying to create my first React app. I have connected the app to the CodeCommit repository but the build on the Amplify console fails with this message:

> 2020-12-14T09:25:04.155Z [ERROR]: !!! Unable to assume specified IAM Role. Please ensure the selected IAM Role has sufficient permissions and the Trust Relationship is configured correctly.

The provision phase works perfectly:

[image: Console screenshot]

I have created the service role *AmplifyConsoleServiceRole-AmplifyRole* as suggested on this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/how-to-service-role-amplify-console.html) and I am logged in as a user with *AdministratorAccess* authorization. Git commits to the repository from my PC console works perfectly.

It is not clear to me what IAM role the AWS Amplify Console is unable to assume. The *AmplifyConsoleServiceRole-AmplifyRole* which I have selected as *Service role* during the App creation I think. The permissions of this role are *AdministratorAccess*, as well. How can I check if the *Trust Relationship* is configured correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've contacted Amazon support. They answered that something is not working on their side using eu-south-1.

I've just tried on eu-central-1 and the build process worked as expected. So no there were no permissions problems but simply a bug. They told me that it will be addressed soon.

Edit: Amazon support team found the problem in the trust relationship to be used with the eu-south-1 region. It must be defined in the following way:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": ["amplify.eu-south-1.amazonaws.com","amplify.amazonaws.com"]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```